# Custom icon/image for slide navigation control buttons like on viber.com

Tags: jquery, css, slider, flexslider

I am using flexslider and i want to change the . . . slide navigation control to my own  icons or image for each slide. like the slide on http://viber.com
if not possible on flexslider in which plugin can i do that.
[image]

Comment: if (No sample code && No Jsfiddle) { No help. };

Comment: Using CSS you can apply a different background for the bullet point. Try something from your end then come up with questions/clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this approach by tweaking with some css and js:

First, hide the default navigation bullets of flexslider using css:

```
.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging {
    display:none;
}
```

Second, add your custom navigation html and design it in whatever way you want. But make sure that the number of slides and custom navigation anchors are same. I used icon images for custom navigation:

```
<div class="custom">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678131-money-16.png" />
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678131-money-16.png" />
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678131-money-16.png" />
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678131-money-16.png" />
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678131-money-16.png" />
</div>
```

Now, bind the click event on these custom navigation elements which in turn triggers the click on the default navigation of flexslider which are hidden.

```
$(document).on('click', '.custom img', function () {
    var index = $('.custom img').index($(this)); //Get the index of clicked navigation element
    var nav = $('.flex-control-nav a')[index]; //Get the navigation element of corresponding index from flexslider.
    $(nav).trigger('click'); //Finally, trigger click
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/VC4L3/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carousel of flex slider like here: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Of course, you have to replace your icon and change some css of carousel to make your slider the same as viber's slider.