# How to Customize Owl Caurosel indecators ? style property needed

Tags: html, css

i was trying to customize the owl caurosel dots and nav. but there is no good style property for styling those navs. if anyone give me the solution i will be helpful.

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224192/owl-carousel-making-custom-navigation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Owl Carousel, making custom navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31224192/owl-carousel-making-custom-navigation)